# Logical or operator not behaving as expected

Tags: python, if-statement, logical-or

```
def Forest(Health,Hunger):
    print'You wake up in the middle of the forest'
    Inventory = 'Inventory: '
    Squirrel =  'Squirrel'
    while True:
        Choice1 = raw_input('You...\n')
        if Choice1 == 'Life' or 'life':
            print('Health: '+str(Health))
            print('Hunger: '+str(Hunger))
        elif Choice1 == 'Look' or 'look':
            print 'You see many trees, and what looks like an edible dead Squirrel, \na waterfall to the north and a village to the south.'
        elif Choice1 == 'Pickup' or 'pickup':
            p1 = raw_input('Pickup what?\n')
            if p1 == Squirrel:
                if Inventory == 'Inventory: ':
                    print'You picked up a Squirrel!'
                    Inventory = Inventory + Squirrel + ', '
                elif Inventory == 'Inventory: Squirrel, ':
                        print'You already picked that up!'
            else:
                print"You can't find a "+str(p1)+"."
        elif Choice1 == 'Inventory' or 'inventory':
            print Inventory
```

I am trying to make it so when it says
You...
you can type either Life, Pickup, Look, or Inventory.
I have way more code on this program I am just showing you a portion.
But every time I run it, it always shows the "Life" portion even if you type "Pickup" or "Look" or "Inventory".
Please help!
Thanks,
John

EDIT:
I think it's just a spacing issue but I am not sure it was running fine earlier...

Comment: Seriously, I think I've now seen exactly this same issue four times in the last two days, for completely different questions.

Comment: You clearly have issues :P

Comment: @DanielRoseman It has happened to me before I just don't know why?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have seen it more!

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've been seeing it repeatedly on Reddit as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the `or` expression. Use this instead:

```
if Choice1.lower() == 'life':
```

or, if you must test against multiple options, use `in`:

```
if Choice1 in ('Life', 'life'):
```

or, if you *must* use `or` then use it like this:

```
if Choice1 == 'Life' or Choice1 == 'life':
```

and expand this to your other `Choice1` tests.

`Choice1 == 'Life' or 'life'` is interpreted as `(Choice1 == 'Life') or ('life')`, with the latter part *always* being True. Even if it *was* interpreted as `Choice1 == ('Life' or 'life')` then the latter part would evaluate to `'Life'` only (it being True as far as boolean tests go), so you'd be testing if `Choice1 == 'Life'` instead, and setting `Choice` to `'life'` would never make the test pass.

Comment: I just changed everything to elif Choice1 in ('Help', 'help):
and it worked perfectly
Thanks!

Comment: I just did some timings. `a in (b, c)` is two to three times faster than `a.lower() == c`, and about 30 % faster than `a == b or a == c`. (tested on Python 3.3.0)

Comment: @TimPietzcker interesting, though for free form input the lower() is probably better as it would catch 'LIfe' or similiar variants.  For completeness, I would probably add a strip() as well, e.g. Choice1.strip().lower()

Answer (score 3):

You have:

```
    if Choice1 == 'Life' or 'life':
```

Which is actually the equivalent of:

```
    if (Choice1 == 'Life') or 'life':
```

A non-empty/non-zero string ('life') will always be treated as true, hence why you end up there.

You either want:

```
    if Choice1 == 'Life' or Choice1 == 'life':
```

or:

```
    if Choice1.lower() == 'life':
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `in`:

```
elif Choice1 in ('Pickup', 'pickup'):
```

Alternatively, you can use regular expressions:

```
import re

elif re.match("[Pp]ickup", Choice1):
```

Separately, I'd use a `set` for your inventory:

```
Inventory = set()
Squirrel =  'Squirrel'
while True:
...
        if p1 == Squirrel:
            if not Inventory:
                print'You picked up a Squirrel!'
                Inventory.add(Squirrel)
            elif Squirrel in Inventory:
                print'You already picked that up!'
```

Comment: It still had the same problem. But I could start using this instead of or.
Thanks

Comment: You really ought to consider the other answers...

Comment: @Chris I am still reading all the answers. Lol